# How can I rotate and zoom in on a Three.js object and share in real time between canvases?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, webrtc

I am working with React, Three.js and WebRTC. I have a 3D object that I can change texture on and display the changes in real-time to all participants in a video call by using data tracks.  Now I want to do the same with rotation and zooming of the object (preferably on mouse interaction) but I'm a bit stuck. At the moment I use orbit controls so it works on the individual canvas. But it seems to do its own thing and I don't know how to share this canvas update with the other participants. Now I do this:

```
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
controls.update()
```

But I need to track the zooming and rotating to be able to share the changes with the other participants. So I want to do like this

```
//on zoom or rotation of 3D object (by mouse interaction with orbit controls)
//share changes
```

How can I achieve this? Is it possible with orbit controls or do I have to use another approach?

Answer (score 0):

`OrbitControls` controls the transformation of the passed camera. If you want to share a camera transformation with multiple clients, consider to track `camera.position` and `camera.quaternion` when working with a perspective camera. By tracking these data and sharing them to other clients, you can keep the respective cameras in sync.

If you add an event listener to the `change` event of `OrbitControls`, you can transmit data only when necessary. Meaning:

```js
controls.addEventListener( 'change', function() {

     transmitData( camera.position, camera.quaternion );

} );
```